# self.skipWaiting() for Safari PWA

Tags: safari, progressive-web-apps

Using chrome browser, one could use `skipWaiting` to replace an older service worker with new one.

I understand this is not supported with Safari (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerGlobalScope/skipWaiting). So what is the alternative?

What is the workflow here to do what `skipWaiting` does?

This is what I have for chrome:

```
self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
  self.skipWaiting();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that browser support info is accurate, see [here](https://jakearchibald.github.io/isserviceworkerready/), it says ok from Safari 11.1.

I have never noticed any difference from Chrome in my PWAs in this respect.  I show a reload button that, when clicked, sends a message to the SW and when received:

```
addEventListener('message', e => {
  if (e.data && e.data.type === 'SKIP_WAITING') skipWaiting();
});
```

Comment: agreed, it seems to work despite that doc saying safari does not support `skipWaiting` - The functionality in [this article](https://dev.to/glukmann/let-users-know-when-you-have-updated-your-service-worker-in-create-react-app-3il9) works perfectly in Safari